# apt-get : trying to resolve ipv6

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, apt

My problem is that when I do an apt-get update is trying to resolve ipv6 ips, and its failing to update/install/etc.

How to disable ipv6 at apt-get?

The ping to www.google.com.ar, resolves to an ipv4.

And this is debian runnung in an OpenVZ container.

This is in a production server and online ONE openvz cluster has this problem! Thats why I want to find other solution than disable ipv6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you've got ipv6 enabled but a broken ipv6 setup, so, probably what you want to do is blacklist the ipv6 module, and restart.

Comment: When searching google (before asking here) I came to that solution.
The problem is that the server is production cluster running OpenVZ containers, to blacklist ipv6 I need reboot I think.
And only one container has the problem!.
Anyway I will be trying the blacklist if I cant found the solution

Answer (score 1):

Unix.SE has two good answers for this:

[If you only want to disable IPv4 for APT](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100887/43720), and you run Debian wheezy or *buntu saucy, or newer, that is, APT 0.9.7.9~exp1 or newer, you can use the `Acquire::ForceIPv4` option, either on the command line (`-o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true`) or in `apt.conf` (`Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";`).

[If you want to prefer IPv4 over IPv6 systemwide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13263/43720) you can uncomment (or append) the line `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100` in `/etc/gai.conf`. I think that this is what applies to your usecase.